# Cosine similarity is slow

Tags: python-3.x, similarity, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a set of sentences, which is encoded using sentence encoder into vectors and I want to find out the most similar sentence to an incoming query.

The search function looks as following:

```
def semantic_search(cleaned_query, data, vectors):
    query_vec = get_features(cleaned_query)[0].ravel()
    res = []
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        qvec = vectors[i].ravel()
        sim = cosine_similarity(query_vec, qvec)
        if sim > 0.5:
            res.append((format(sim * 100, '.2f'), data[i]))
    return sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)[:15]
```

where `cleaned_query` is a preprocessed query in a string form, `data` is a list with all sentences (300 in total) and `vectors` contains encoded vectors for each sentence in data with dimensions (300,500).

When i send a query to my service is takes around 10-12 seconds to process one, which too slow, in my opinion. I have done some debugging and realized that the issue is in `cosine_similarity` function, which is implemented as following:

```
import numpy as np
def cosine_similarity(v1, v2):
    mag1 = np.linalg.norm(v1)
    mag2 = np.linalg.norm(v2)
    if (not mag1) or (not mag2):
        return 0
    return np.dot(v1, v2) / (mag1 * mag2)
```

I have tried to look into different implementations and found some that works quite fast using numba - `nb_cosine`, but it delivers not good results, meaning that the `cosine_similarity`, which is above, delivers more correct and meaningful results. Here is the implementation with numba:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def nb_cosine(x, y):
    xx,yy,xy=0.0,0.0,0.0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        xx+=x[i]*x[i]
        yy+=y[i]*y[i]
        xy+=x[i]*y[i]
    return 1.0-xy/np.sqrt(xx*yy)
```

Can anyone suggest, how can I optimize my `cosine_similarity` function to work faster? The 300 sentences are always the same. And just in case, if needed, below is `get_features` function:

```
def get_features(texts):
    if type(texts) is str:
        texts = [texts]
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        return sess.run(embed(texts))
```

Comment: you can try with below link, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if you’re calculating the cosine similarity correctly
there; you may want to check some values you’re getting and make sure
they make sense.

Anyway, one way to speed things up would be to precalculate and store
the magnitude of each vector for your 300 sentences, and also
precalculate the magnitude of `query_vec`. As the code is now, you’re
recalculating the magnitude of each sentence with every call, and
calculating the magnitude of `query_vec` 300 times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I understand what you mean, but it doesn't do the code any better - the time needed for processing is almost the same.

Comment: Really. I’m surprised, I would have thought all those recalculations were taking a fair chunk of the total time. Sorry this wasn’t useful.